# What are these unexpected network devices which appear in kernel log?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, network-interface, pop-os

I have `enp7s0` (ethernet) and `wlp5s0` (wifi) that I've been using, but there's some other network interfaces that I don't recognise that keep showing periodically in dmesg.  What are they, and how can I remove them?

```
$ sudo dmesg -w
[ 5400.052789] device veth517d19f entered promiscuous mode
[ 5400.052861] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth517d19f) entered blocking state
[ 5400.052862] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth517d19f) entered forwarding state
[ 5400.213261] eth0: renamed from veth244244e
[ 5400.222378] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth517d19f: link becomes ready
[ 5568.791784] veth244244e: renamed from eth0
[ 5568.810950] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth517d19f) entered disabled state
[ 5568.830903] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth517d19f) entered disabled state
[ 5568.831278] device veth517d19f left promiscuous mode
[ 5568.831280] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth517d19f) entered disabled state
[ 5568.880757] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered blocking state
[ 5568.880760] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered disabled state
[ 5568.880814] device veth011f3f5 entered promiscuous mode
[ 5568.880962] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered blocking state
[ 5568.880964] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered forwarding state
[ 5569.077840] eth0: renamed from veth6e8382e
[ 5569.093718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth011f3f5: link becomes ready
[ 5737.805813] veth6e8382e: renamed from eth0
[ 5737.823318] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered disabled state
[ 5737.843811] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered disabled state
[ 5737.844340] device veth011f3f5 left promiscuous mode
[ 5737.844344] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth011f3f5) entered disabled state
[ 5737.893657] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered blocking state
[ 5737.893661] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered disabled state
[ 5737.893736] device vethd8bfbd6 entered promiscuous mode
[ 5737.893886] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered blocking state
[ 5737.893890] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered forwarding state
[ 5738.172548] eth0: renamed from veth7906981
[ 5738.188736] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethd8bfbd6: link becomes ready
[ 5906.354088] veth7906981: renamed from eth0
[ 5906.369700] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered disabled state
[ 5906.389362] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered disabled state
[ 5906.389734] device vethd8bfbd6 left promiscuous mode
[ 5906.389737] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(vethd8bfbd6) entered disabled state
[ 5906.443306] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered blocking state
[ 5906.443309] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered disabled state
[ 5906.443354] device veth7a88bf4 entered promiscuous mode
[ 5906.443425] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered blocking state
[ 5906.443426] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered forwarding state
[ 5906.637888] eth0: renamed from veth9acd0b3
[ 5906.659074] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth7a88bf4: link becomes ready
[ 6074.517484] veth9acd0b3: renamed from eth0
[ 6074.529161] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered disabled state
[ 6074.544507] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered disabled state
[ 6074.544814] device veth7a88bf4 left promiscuous mode
[ 6074.544815] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7a88bf4) entered disabled state
[ 6074.582235] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7cc8283) entered blocking state
[ 6074.582238] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7cc8283) entered disabled state
[ 6074.582284] device veth7cc8283 entered promiscuous mode
[ 6074.582354] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7cc8283) entered blocking state
[ 6074.582355] br-b6747aa2af8f: port 1(veth7cc8283) entered forwarding state
[ 6074.771300] eth0: renamed from veth5a7e47a
[ 6074.791442] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth7cc8283: link becomes ready
```

```
$ ip -br -c addr show
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
enp7s0           UP             10.10.10.1/8 fe80::a66e:xxxx:e22:xxxx/64
wlp5s0           UP             192.168.18.193/24 fe80::d28c:xxxx:6da5:xxxx/64
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24
virbr1           DOWN           192.168.39.1/24
lxcbr0           DOWN           10.0.3.1/24
br-e32feb7cbdc6  DOWN           172.23.0.1/16
br-ef8e425d866f  DOWN           172.21.0.1/16
br-0d1de33a9fd1  DOWN           172.18.0.1/16
br-1535ef132d94  DOWN           172.24.0.1/16
br-3daca6071d2e  DOWN           172.20.0.1/16
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16
br-80a4ad7261ed  DOWN           172.22.0.1/16
br-b6747aa2af8f  UP             172.19.0.1/16 fe80::42:bff:xxxx:xxxx/64
vethed6ff23@if18 UP             fe80::fc36:adff:xxxx:xxxx/64
vethecf0d6f@if38 UP             fe80::c8a6:48ff:xxxx:xxxx/64
```

How can I know which software created those?

Comment: You are running docker, which has tons of bridges and virtual devices, depending on how you configure it. As they are down, they may be "leftovers". The `lxcbr0` bridge is probably from some LXC containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list looks like:

- lo = loopback
- enp7s0 = ethernet
- lp5s0 = wlan
- virbr* = virtual bridge
- lxcbr* = lxc/lxd
- docker* = docker
- br* = docker bridge
- veth* = virtual Ethernet devices

you can use the **nmcli**(network manager)

and run:

`$ nmcli device list`

for your **docker** containers run:

`$ docker network ls`

than

`$ docker network inspect [USE THE NETWORK ID FROM THE FIRST COMMAND]`

try this to to get a list of the network devices:

`$ echo /sys/class/net/*`

You can get more informations with **udevadm**:

`$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/[NETWORK DEVICE NAME]`

Example:

`$ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/enp0s25`

With **ip**:

`$ ip -r link`

`$ ip -br link`

`$ ip -br -c link show`

`$ ip token`

`$ ip -s -s link show dev docker0`

With **lshw**:

`$ lshw -class network`

`$ lshw -class network -short`

**Update**

Get more informations from this manpages:

- **man systemd.netdev**
- **man systemd.link**
- **man systemd.network**

More detail information with **networkctl**

`$ networkctl`

`$ networkctl status`

`$ networkctl status --all`

Comment: Documentation of the /sys/class/net/<iface>/name_assign_type https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net

Comment: ah nice, so that veth is from docker '__') after pruning unused docker (`docker network prune`) it's all gone

Comment: @Kokizzu | yes lovely docker :-)  there is also the possibility(if you want to go deeper) with "linux network namespace interfaces and devices" https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html